# ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, spring-boot, gradle

I am having a problem, with my tests. I am not sure I understand it tells me that it can't find the Application context. This is what I have:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = StuffApp.class)
public class StuffAppTest {
//... some tests
}
```

Maybe is worth mentioning that this happens after I migrate from maven to gradle, before the migration the tests were passing. Here I leave you the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
    at org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.mycompany.stuff.StuffApp]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException## Heading ##: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$900(ConfigurationClassParser.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:804)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:774)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:315)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:232)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:691)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:528)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:180)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:51)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:88)
    at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:75)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:685)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getRelated(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1058)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getAnnotationAttributes(ConfigurationClassParser.java:1039)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.collectImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:538)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:511)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:302)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:242)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:589)
    ... 42 more
```

In my gradle I have the following plugins and dependencies:

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.1.2.RELEASE"
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.14'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'checkstyle'
apply plugin: 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok'
apply plugin: 'project-report'

dependencies {

    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.1.2.RELEASE'

    implementation 'io.opentracing.brave:brave-opentracing:0.33.10'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:2.9.2'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:2.9.2'

    implementation 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-csv:1.6'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.8.1'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3'

    testImplementation 'net.javacrumbs.json-unit:json-unit:1.29.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.23.4'
    testImplementation 'com.github.tomakehurst:wiremock-standalone:2.18.0'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:2.1.2.RELEASE'
}
```

Comment: you should also leave us your build script... (at least plugins and dependencies )

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I just added some of the contents of my gradle.build file(plugins and dependencies)

Comment: see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12985 : it looks like you have similar issue with some incompatible version between (maybe) spring-cloud modules and Spring Boot version.  hope this helps

Comment: @M.Ricciuti I just removed those two dependencies that referred to cloud, but there was no difference. I am unsure what could be conflicting? I had a look at that link but unfortunately there's no conclusion in there.

Comment: @babylonian , any updates on this issue ?