# java.io.FileNotFoundException : ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration.class cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, version, filenotfoundexception

After upgrading spring-boot version from `'1.5.11.RELEASE'` to `'2.1.6.RELEASE'` i am facing runtime exception after successful compilation and build like below.
[image]

I have tried adding manual spring.factories inside resources and the result is same. I am not getting any other solutions in internet.

The project is multimodule gradle project.
Dependencies used are below - 
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54346367/serverpropertiesautoconfiguration-class-cannot-be-opened-because-it-does-not-exi

Comment: @StephenC, you can also see my comment and no solutions given.

Comment: Asking the same question again because the first one has no answers is the wrong approach.  You should post a bonus.  That is what reputation points are for.  (At least one reason ....)

Comment: @Jet - I think I need a little more context to figure out what's going on here.  
1. Are you attempting to use one of the sub-modules as a spring-boot-autoconfigure jar?
2. Can you share anything about your project's build.gradle that could help us see what you are doing?
3.  Did you happen to first upgrade from 1.5.x to 2.0.x? That by itself is a huge upgrade documented by this guide: https://git.io/fj7qp - the advice on this page also is to first upgrade to the latest 1.5.x (1.5.22), then to 2.0.0, then to other versions since so much changed in the newer spring boot versions.